# nginx not providing performance gain to R plumber API hosted on AWS with Docker

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to scale up a computationally expensive R Plumber API using Docker and AWS and I want to handle multiple requests, thus I want to use Nginx to help with this.

I'm following this tutorial: https://www.knowru.com/blog/how-to-scale-up-credit-model-apis-using-aws/ which is directly applicable to my use case however I'm not experiencing the the performance gain suggested.

The steps I'm implementing are summarised as follows:

1) I create some data to test the API, which can be replicated using the following R code (ensuring my data is in the correct location when I run the following docker commands):

```
new.data <- list(
  Status.of.existing.checking.account='A11'
  , Duration.in.month=20
  , Credit.history='A32'
  , Savings.account.bonds='A65'
)

write_json(new.data, "~/Documents/data.json")
```

2) Using Docker via the command line, I spin up an EC2 instance. The only key difference between my own approach and the tutorial is the: **amazonec2-open-port 8000** line.

```
docker-machine create \
    --driver amazonec2 \
    --amazonec2-access-key xxx \
    --amazonec2-secret-key yyy \
    --amazonec2-region zzz \
    --amazonec2-instance-type t2.small \
    --amazonec2-open-port 8000 \
    nginx-testing-machine
```

3) I build the Docker image from the knowru github repo and then run.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker build -t 
knowru/plumber_example https://github.com/Knowru/plumber_example.git

eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -p 
8000:8000 -d knowru/plumber_example
```

4) After finding out the IP of my EC2 using **docker-machine ip nginx-testing-server**, I test the API using siege.

```
siege -H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
"http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/predict POST < data.json" -b -c 10 -r 100
```

That provides me with the following results:

```
Transactions:               1000 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              13.32 secs
Data transferred:           0.03 MB
Response time:              0.13 secs
Transaction rate:          75.08 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                9.74
Successful transactions:        1000
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.15
Shortest transaction:           0.06
```

5) I now add four other Docker containers mapping to port 8000 for each one.

```
eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -p 
8001:8000 -d knowru/plumber_example

eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -p 
8002:8000 -d knowru/plumber_example

eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -p 
8003:8000 -d knowru/plumber_example

eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -p 
8004:8000 -d knowru/plumber_example
```

6) I'm somewhat unsure why but the tutorial clones the git repo on the EC2, which is done here:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && git clone 
https://github.com/Knowru/plumber_example.git
```

I then run the nginx image (noting the port mapping of 80:8000 which is something I'm unsure of):

```
eval "$(docker-machine env nginx-testing-server)" && docker run -v 
/home/ubuntu/plumber_example:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro -d -p 80:8000 nginx
```

7) I siege again running the same test

```
siege -H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
"http://IP_ADDRESS:8000/predict POST < data.json" -b -c 10 -r 100
```

which provides me with quite similar looking results

```
Transactions:               1000 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:              14.04 secs
Data transferred:           0.03 MB
Response time:              0.14 secs
Transaction rate:          71.23 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                9.71
Successful transactions:        1000
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.21
Shortest transaction:           0.07
```

The results are incredibly similar so I'm doing something incorrect. The only thing I've changed is the ports so it suggests to me that the port mapping is wrong. If that is the case, how do I do this correctly & what are the restrictions/requirements to use nginx? Thank you in advance for any help on this - I assume it's something quite simple for someone experienced with this technology.

Comment: While I think you followed the article correctly, the article itself does not have the proper `nginx` config so that is why it doesn't seem to improve anything.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Are you aware of any resources which would help to ensure the nginx config is correct so I can implement this?